# NativeScript - Karma unit test not running with a promise

Tags: angular, unit-testing, nativescript, karma-jasmine

I'm writing an app with NativeScript 6.4.1 and Angular 8.2.0. I'm using karma & jasmine to write my unit tests.

One of my services has a function that returns promise in it and I would like to write a unit test to test this function.

I read the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

I should be able to write tests with asynchronous calls with the 'done()' function.

My promise is not being called in the test:

```
describe('SsoAuthenticationService', () => {

  let service: SsoAuthenticationService;

  beforeEach(nsTestBedBeforeEach([], [SsoAuthenticationService]));

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.get(SsoAuthenticationService);
  });

  it('getHttpHeader - token data exisits and it is valid', (done: DoneFn) => {

    const result = service.getHttpHeader();
    console.log('1'); //called

    result.then((res) => {
      console.log('2'); //not being called
      expect(res).not.toBeNull(); //not being called
      done();
    });

console.log('3'); //called
```

service:

```
export class SsoAuthenticationService {

    public getHttpHeader(): Promise<string> {
        return Promise.resolve('a');
    }
```

}

How can I get my unit test to work and run the expect block?

Comment: Did you try adding a catch block to your unit test to make sure it's not failing?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be fine with no errors. result.then() is not being called it seems.

Comment: Should  return Promise.resolve('a); not be  return Promise.resolve('a'); (note the closing quote)

Comment: That's just a typo. The result is the same.